# Jquery change background size AND image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change both background-image and background-size (so it fits the div)

```
$(".clickableimg").click(function() {
    var choosenpic = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#image").val(choosenpic);
    $("#preview").css("background","url(backgrounds/"+choosenpic+")");
    $("#preview").css("background","size('50%')");
});
```

Do you know how I can change more css attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the background style twice overwrites it, so only the last one will stick, you'll need to use valid CSS properties, like `background-image` and `background-size` to change them seperately :

```
$(".clickableimg").on('click', function() {
    var choosenpic = this.id;
    $("#image").val(choosenpic);
    $("#preview").css({
        'background-image' : 'url(backgrounds/'+choosenpic+')',
        'background-size'  : '50%'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that your code works correctly because I think you mean

```
  $("#preview").css("background-image","url(backgrounds/"+choosenpic+")");
```

but if what you have works already then cheers.

You can change any css attributes as long as its supported by the browser.

```
  $("#preview").css("display", "none")
  $("#preview").css("width", "5000px")
  $("#preview").css("text-shadow", "...")
  $("#preview").css("box-shadow", "...")
  $("#preview").css("border", "...") ..
```

I can go on and on..but here is a list of some of CSS3 properties you can play with

http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you're new to javascript you should first look at how javascript basically works before starting with a framework like jQuery. According to your question the following jquery plugin should help you to accomplish your task:
https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

This plugin will help you get it working in IE8 too.